# Unexpected token error on axios import on a nativescript-vue project

Tags: vue.js, webpack, axios, nativescript

I have a nativescript & vue project and I am trying to do axios calls.

As soon as I install axios package via npm and import it to my project, tns run ios command gives this errors:

```
Project successfully built.
The build result is located at: /Users/admin/Desktop/Sites/frontent/platforms/ios/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/frontendnative.app
Installing on device 4B430620-3B24-43CB-B743-705A8E9FB2D7...
Successfully installed on device with identifier '4B430620-3B24-43CB-B743-705A8E9FB2D7'.
Successfully transferred all files on device 4B430620-3B24-43CB-B743-705A8E9FB2D7.
Restarting application on device 4B430620-3B24-43CB-B743-705A8E9FB2D7...
Successfully synced application com.frontend on device 4B430620-3B24-43CB-B743-705A8E9FB2D7.
Successfully transferred bundle.64b9e6405a9a75fb778e.hot-update.js on device 4B430620-3B24-43CB-B743-705A8E9FB2D7.
Successfully transferred 64b9e6405a9a75fb778e.hot-update.json on device 4B430620-3B24-43CB-B743-705A8E9FB2D7.
***** Fatal JavaScript exception - application has been terminated. *****
Native stack trace:
1   0x10a60371a NativeScript::reportFatalErrorBeforeShutdown(JSC::ExecState*, JSC::Exception*, bool)
2   0x10a64f14c -[TNSRuntime executeModule:referredBy:]
3   0x109f21713 main
4   0x7fff516ecd29 start
5   0x1
JavaScript stack trace:
file:///node_modules/debug/src/node.js:201:2
at promiseReactionJob([native code])
at require([native code])
at anonymous(file:///app/bundle.js:1:102)
at evaluate([native code])
at moduleEvaluation([native code])
at promiseReactionJob([native code])
JavaScript error:
file:///node_modules/debug/src/node.js:201:2: JS ERROR SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':'. Parse error.
(CoreFoundation) *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NativeScript encountered a fatal error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':'. Parse error.
at
file:///node_modules/debug/src/node.js:201:2
at promiseReactionJob([native code])
at require([native code])
at anonymous(file:///app/bundle.js:1:102)
at evaluate([native code])
at moduleEvaluation([native code])
at promiseReactionJob([native code])
', reason: '(null)'
*** First throw call stack:
(
0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23baa1ee __exceptionPreprocess + 350
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff50864b20 objc_exception_throw + 48
2   NativeScript                        0x000000010a603bbf _ZN12NativeScript30reportFatalErrorBeforeShutdownEPN3JSC9ExecStateEPNS0_9ExceptionEb + 1455
3   NativeScript                        0x000000010a64f14c -[TNSRuntime executeModule:referredBy:] + 668
4   frontendtest          0x0000000109f21713 main + 179
5   libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff516ecd29 start + 1
6   ???         <…>
NativeScript caught signal 6.
Native Stack:
1   0x10a64dcb1 sig_handler(int)
2   0x7fff518c9b1d _sigtramp
3   0x1
4   0x7fff517b9a3c abort
5   0x7fff4f6d27f8 __cxa_bad_cast
6   0x7fff4f6d29c7 demangling_unexpected_handler()
7   0x7fff50864d7c _objc_terminate()
8   0x7fff4f6dfe97 std::__terminate(void (*)())
9   0x7fff4f6df8fe __cxa_get_exception_ptr
10  0x7fff4f6df8c5 __cxxabiv1::exception_cleanup_func(_Unwind_Reason_Code, _Unwind_Exception*)
11  0x7fff50864c44 _objc_exception_destructor(void*)
12  0x10a603bbf NativeScript::reportFatalErrorBeforeShutdown(JSC::ExecState*, JSC::Exception*, bool)
13  0x10a64f14c -[TNSRuntime executeModule:referredBy:]
14  0x109f21713 main
15  0x7fff516ecd29 start
16  0x1
JS Stack:
***** Fatal JavaScript exception - application has been terminated. *****
Native stack trace:
1   0x10dd6f71a NativeScript::reportFatalErrorBeforeShutdown(JSC::ExecState*, JSC::Exception*, bool)
2   0x10ddbb14c -[TNSRuntime executeModule:referredBy:]
3   0x10d68d713 main
4   0x7fff516ecd29 start
5   0x1
JavaScript stack trace:
file:///node_modules/debug/src/node.js:201:2
at promiseReactionJob([native code])
at require([native code])
at anonymous(file:///app/bundle.js:1:102)
at evaluate([native code])
at moduleEvaluation([native code])
at promiseReactionJob([native code])
JavaScript error:
file:///node_modules/debug/src/node.js:201:2: JS ERROR SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':'. Parse error.
(CoreFoundation) *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NativeScript encountered a fatal error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':'. Parse error.
at
file:///node_modules/debug/src/node.js:201:2
at promiseReactionJob([native code])
at require([native code])
at anonymous(file:///app/bundle.js:1:102)
at evaluate([native code])
at moduleEvaluation([native code])
at promiseReactionJob([native code])
', reason: '(null)'
*** First throw call stack:
(
0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23baa1ee __exceptionPreprocess + 350
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff50864b20 objc_exception_throw + 48
2   NativeScript                        0x000000010dd6fbbf _ZN12NativeScript30reportFatalErrorBeforeShutdownEPN3JSC9ExecStateEPNS0_9ExceptionEb + 1455
3   NativeScript                        0x000000010ddbb14c -[TNSRuntime executeModule:referredBy:] + 668
4   frontendtest          0x000000010d68d713 main + 179
5   libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff516ecd29 start + 1
6   ???         <…>
NativeScript caught signal 6.
Native Stack:
1   0x10ddb9cb1 sig_handler(int)
2   0x7fff518c9b1d _sigtramp
3   0x1
4   0x7fff517b9a3c abort
5   0x7fff4f6d27f8 __cxa_bad_cast
6   0x7fff4f6d29c7 demangling_unexpected_handler()
7   0x7fff50864d7c _objc_terminate()
8   0x7fff4f6dfe97 std::__terminate(void (*)())
9   0x7fff4f6df8fe __cxa_get_exception_ptr
10  0x7fff4f6df8c5 __cxxabiv1::exception_cleanup_func(_Unwind_Reason_Code, _Unwind_Exception*)
11  0x7fff50864c44 _objc_exception_destructor(void*)
12  0x10dd6fbbf NativeScript::reportFatalErrorBeforeShutdown(JSC::ExecState*, JSC::Exception*, bool)
13  0x10ddbb14c -[TNSRuntime executeModule:referredBy:]
14  0x10d68d713 main
15  0x7fff516ecd29 start
16  0x1
JS Stack:
```

In main.js I import it like this:

```
import axios from 'axios'
```

and do a post call in a component like this:

```js
return axios.post('/api/v1/auth/login', {
      email,
      password
    }).then(response => {
      console.log(response)
    }).catch((error) => console.log(error))
```

It's very strange, but I couldn't figure it out. The error is gone if I remove axios completely.
How can I fix it?

Project dependencies in package.json

```
"core-js": "^3.2.1",
"frontend-core": "file:../frontend-core",
"moment": "^2.24.0",
"nativescript-app-sync": "^1.0.7",
"nativescript-carousel": "^6.1.1",
"nativescript-geolocation": "^5.1.0",
"nativescript-localize": "^4.2.0",
"nativescript-theme-core": "^2.0.23",
"nativescript-ui-calendar": "^5.0.0",
"nativescript-ui-dataform": "^5.1.1",
"nativescript-ui-sidedrawer": "^7.0.3",
"nativescript-vue": "^2.4.0",
"nativescript-vue-lifecycle-hooks": "^1.0.0",
"nativescript-vue-navigator": "^0.2.0",
"tns-core-modules": "^6.1.1",
"axios": "^0.19.0",
"vue": "^2.6.10",
"vuex": "^3.1.1"
```

Comment: Looks like your response is not JSON, try setting `responseType` to `text`. If still facing issue, share a Playground sample.

Comment: I don't think it is related to response, because I also tried to use https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1 -which is a JSON endpoint-.

Comment: Is it reproduced with Playground?

Comment: I'll check, but I think it will be hard to move whole setup to playground.

Comment: You don't have to move anything, all you need is to install Axios and adjust your require statement (relative path), hit the API.

Comment: It seems like it works with pure setup with only axios plugin on playground. There must be something else that cause the issue. Maybe it doesn't like another package. I'll update the post if I can figure it out.

Comment: I hope your endpoints are https, if http then remember you will have to allow clear text traffic.

Comment: You may also try the chrome debugger or network proxy in local machine to make sure you are hitting the right endpoint.

Comment: The endpoint I try is 100% fine. I tried to change import 'axios' to 'axios/dist/axios' and the error is gone. Strange, but still investigating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like axios has problems on NativeScript + Vue. It worked when I change
`import axios from 'axios'` to `import axios from 'axios/dist/axios'`